# Sets and Quantifiers

Tags: abstract-algebra, quantifiers

[image]

I have difficulty converting sentences into 'mathematical language'.

According to my work above

```
1. Have I understood the problem correctly?
2. Is my answer correct?
```

Comment: Actually I would have interpreted the second part as the stronger $\exists t\forall x$, but natural language is often ambiguous. - It is also worth contemplating wether the "you" of the staement is $\in P$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add:
$\land (\lnot [\forall x \in P , \forall t \in T , F(x,t)])$

Comment: Thank you so much.
Would it be possible to write this without the not sign?

Comment: $\land [\exists x \in P , \exists t \in T ,\lnot F(x,t)]$